# Why doesn't Selenium @FindBy work with name, xpath, css

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Java program using Selenium and would like to use `@FindBy()`, but I can't solve the problem. My program is composed of several lines. I would like to share tasks between classes. And for that, I started with identity verification. I created this class which includes login and password.

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;

public class LoginPageNew {

    WebDriver webDriver;

    public LoginPageNew(WebDriver driver) {
        this.webDriver = driver;
    }

    @FindBy(css = "[name='username']")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement username;

    @FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "password")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement password;

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//button[normalize-space()='Login']")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement submit_btn;

    public void loginPage() {
        username.sendKeys("Admin");
        password.sendKeys("admin123");
        submit_btn.click();
    }
}
```

And I created this class

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class BrowserFactory {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver startBrowser(String browserName, String url) {
        if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
        return driver;
    }
}
```

And finally this test class

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class VerifyLoginPage {

    @Test
    public void checkValidUser() {
        WebDriver webDriver = BrowserFactory.startBrowser("chrome", "http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
        LoginPageNew pageNew = PageFactory.initElements(webDriver, LoginPageNew.class);
            pageNew.loginPage();
    }
}
```

For me, I would like to work with the site "https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/" with login and password "Admin" and "admin123" with this architecture to do the test.

And I used

```
@FindBy(name="username"), @FindBy(css = "[name='username']"), 
@Find By(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Username']")
@Find By(xpath = "(//input[@placeholder='Username'])[1]")
@Find By(how = How. NAME, using = "username")...
```

But there is no solution, always the same error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name='username']"}
 (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.76)
 For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#no_such_element
 Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'
 System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.16'
 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
 Command: [f3cd14b65540143dd77567fdbdd70945, findElement {using=css selector, value= 
 [name='username']}]
 Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 109.0.5414.76, 
 chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604da..., userDataDir: 
 C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\T...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:64620}, 
 networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: 
 Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:64620/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 109.0.5414.76, setWindowRect: 
 true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 
 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, 
 webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
```

Comment: you probably need: input[name='username']  (You've just got some syntax problems...)

Comment: This is not the issue with web locators techniques, rather than issue with webdriver initialization. The web driver is not able to identify the elements as there were no instructions to wait until objects are visible during runtime. Adding below statement _**driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);**_ would fix the issue.

Comment: You can to use this code. It's very easy and efficient :) webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add this code

```
webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

thank you **BMW83**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).